# Loading classification model in TensorFlow 2.6 getting Assertion Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have tuned and trained a ResNet50V2 model on some data, and saved a model checkpoint. Then I got the error attached below when trying to load the model for manual evaluation a while back. I fixed it then by simply upgrading TensorFlow from a version below 2.5 (I think it was 2.4) to version 2.6 and the evaluation worked.

However, I haven't changed anything in the script since and now I'm getting this error back. The TensorFlow version still is 2.6, I just would like to know what could cause the following AssertionError to try and reason it through; I don't really understand what "Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values" means, and the solutions I found online were irrelevant to the problem.

```
AssertionError: Some Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values, likely due to changes in the Python program: [<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3,) dtype=int64, numpy=array([ 4282272077633878287, -7283986953186424327, -5126519832639123830])>]
```

I know the question is vague, because ideally I would like to know what could go wrong and lead to this, not just in my specific case.

Edit 1:
The whole raised error is as shown below.

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-a95079b96a23> in <module>
----> 1 model =  tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path,compile = False) #tf.keras.models.load_weights(model_path) #
      2 model.summary()

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/saving/save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, options)
    203         filepath = path_to_string(filepath)
    204         if isinstance(filepath, str):
--> 205           return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
    206 
    207   raise IOError(

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in load(path, compile, options)
    138   for node_id, loaded_node in keras_loader.loaded_nodes.items():
    139     nodes_to_load[keras_loader.get_path(node_id)] = loaded_node
--> 140   loaded = tf.__internal__.saved_model.load_partial(path, nodes_to_load, options=options)
    141 
    142   # Finalize the loaded layers and remove the extra tracked dependencies.

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in load_partial(export_dir, filters, tags, options)
    767     A dictionary mapping node paths from the filter to loaded objects.
    768   """
--> 769   return load_internal(export_dir, tags, options, filters=filters)
    770 
    771 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in load_internal(export_dir, tags, options, loader_cls, filters)
    901       try:
    902         loader = loader_cls(object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir,
--> 903                             ckpt_options, options, filters)
    904       except errors.NotFoundError as err:
    905         raise FileNotFoundError(

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in __init__(self, object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir, ckpt_options, save_options, filters)
    163 
    164     if not save_options.experimental_skip_checkpoint:
--> 165       self._restore_checkpoint()
    166       for node in self._nodes:
    167         if isinstance(node, tracking.CapturableResource):

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in _restore_checkpoint(self)
    475     else:
    476       load_status = saver.restore(variables_path, self._checkpoint_options)
--> 477       load_status.assert_existing_objects_matched()
    478     checkpoint = load_status._checkpoint
    479 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py in assert_existing_objects_matched(self)
    851           ("Some Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values, likely "
    852            "due to changes in the Python program: %s") %
--> 853           (list(unused_python_objects),))
    854     return self
    855 

AssertionError: Some Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values, likely due to changes in the Python program: [<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3,) dtype=int64, numpy=array([6311003893102156679, 6438069434235288015, 3327528000006074075])>]
```

Comment: could you paste a code snippet where error raises?

Comment: @MiguelTrejo it is barely useful since it happens when I use the tf.keras.models.load_model function, but sure :)